# Dom manipulation for flipping the class for <i>

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using the Angular 5 in the new project first time and new to his technology.

My component.html looks like this :-

```
<div *ngIf="_leftNavList.length > 0" class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar">

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">

                <li *ngFor="let lx of _leftNavList" (click)="navitemClick($event, lx)">
                    <a [routerLink]=[lx.routerlink]>{{lx.linktext}}</a>
                    <i class="invisible fas fa-circle icon-background greendot"></i>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

My component.ts file looks like this :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ILeftNavLinks } from '../interfaces/ILeftNavLinks';
import { LeftNavService } from './leftnav.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-leftnav',
    templateUrl: './leftnav.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./leftnav.component.css'],
    providers: [LeftNavService]
})


export class LeftNavComponent {
    public _leftNavList: ILeftNavLinks[] = [];

   constructor(private _navService: LeftNavService) {  }

    ngOnInit(): void {         
        this._leftNavList = this._navService.getNavLinks();          
    }

 navitemClick(event, item){
    //How do i access the dom element and switch the classes
}
}
```

Based on the user click on the LI item, I want to change the **invisible class to visible** for the clicked LI. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[ngClass]` to mutate the class from a component.

```
<i [ngClass]="classType" class="fas fa-circle icon-background greendot"></i>
```

ts

```
classType = 'invisible'

 navitemClick(event, item){
    this.classType = 'visible'
}
```

**Update**

Since Op mentioned a ngfor we need to Add a new property to _leftNavList called `classType` and set the default value to `invisible`. Then change the values from `navitemClick`

```
 navitemClick(event, item){
     item.classType = 'visible'
 }
```

add the new property inside the `ngClass`

```
<i [ngClass]="lx.classType" class="fas fa-circle icon-background greendot"></i>
```

Comment: @sachila It works, but i want to change the class for the clicked item only. currently it is doing for all the items. Please suggest.

Comment: I think my scenario is also evolving now.. I have to make it work like a toggle now. Only one LI will have the visible class upon the click, the rest of the LI will have invisible class.